# Executing statement with clob?

Tags: python, cx-oracle, clob

Two Queries:

First one as:

```
with table_1 as ( select 'Item '||level item_name, level lvl from dual connect by level <= 10000 ) select * from table_1 where lvl in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,....,997,998,999,1000)
```

And another as:

```
with table_1 as ( select 'Item '||level item_name, level lvl from dual connect by level <= 10000 ) select * from table_1 where lvl in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,....,1997,1998,1999,2000)
```

I can run the first query in cx-oracle but I cannot run the second one. I know the size of the second one is different and concept of LOB/CLOB comes in play but I am not sure how to use it here.

Can I create a CLOB and execute the query or am I thinking of it all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of 1 thousand values you can put in an "IN" condition. It is documented below:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions014.htm

> You can specify up to 1000 expressions in expression_list.

If you need more you will need to place those values in a table and do something like:

```
select ... where lvl in (select lvl from lvl_table)
```

I would question however why you are using IN? Your list looks like a contiguous list of numbers, and if that is accurate you could simple use something like

```
where level <= 10000
```

or any combination of using "between" or greater than, less than with "or".